# Adding marker on Google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

This may be a repeated question (looked at many answers before writing it), but I am unable to solve it.

I want to simple integrate google maps into my swift app. All is working great except getting that marker to show on the map. I am following google map api docs, but no luck.

Here is the body of the function:

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        /**Testing Google Maps **/
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        //let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        googleMapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)



        let  position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
        marker.title = "Hello World"
        marker.map = googleMapView
```

This is executing in viewDidLoad(). I get the map to show but its not showing any marker.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
var marker = GMSMarker()
marker.postion = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10,10)
marker.title ="ENTER TITLE"
marker.snippet ="ENTER SNIPPET"
marker.map = googleMapView
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

After long trying and researching, got it to work by tweaking one line to get the same map view in the UIView with type GMSMap:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        googleMapView.camera = camera //This line
        googleMapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set the delegate of mapView in  `viewDidLoad`

```
mapView.delegate = self
```

and accept  `GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol in your `ViewController` like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
}
```